# How to load image dataset for SVM image classification task

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a linear SVM classifier (AD vs NC) for the classification of Alzheimer's Disease by using MRI images. How can I load the image dataset correctly?

I found an example of SVM image classification and I tried to run through the trial, but there was an error when loading the dataset.
The folder name is "images"
there are five subfolders in "images". They are named as doller_bill, sunflower, pizza, dog, and ball. Each subfolder contains 50-60 photos as jpg format. The followings are the sample codes I downloaded.
[download from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrwry.png)

```py
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np %matplotlib notebook 
from sklearn import svm, metrics, datasets 
from sklearn.utils import Bunch 
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from skimage.io import imread 
from skimage.transform import resize

def load_image_files(container_path, dimension=(64, 64)): 
    image_dir = Path(container_path) 
    folders = [directory for directory in image_dir.iterdir() if 
    directory.is_dir()] 
    categories = [fo.name for fo in folders]

    descr = "A image classification dataset"
    images = []
    flat_data = []
    target = []
    for i, direc in enumerate(folders):
        for file in direc.iterdir():
            img = skimage.io.imread(file)
            img_resized = resize(img, dimension, anti_aliasing=True, 
            mode='reflect')
            flat_data.append(img_resized.flatten()) 
            images.append(img_resized)
            target.append(i)
        flat_data = np.array(flat_data)
        target = np.array(target)
        images = np.array(images)

    return Bunch(data=flat_data,
             target=target,
             target_names=categories,
             images=images,
             DESCR=descr)

image_dataset = load_image_files("images/")
```

However, when I run through the codes, it appeared an error as follows

> NameError: name 'skimage' is not defined

So, would you please help me to figure out how to load the image dataset.
For instance, I have a folder named "images"
the subfolders are named as "MRI images_NC", "MRI images_AD", 
Accordingly, each folder contains 1500 photos approximately.

Thanks again.

Comment: Change `img = skimage.io.imread(file)` to `img = imread(file)`

Comment: Dear guys, I have installed skimage properly before. So I supposed this is not the case that I didn't install the package.

Comment: It is not the problem with the package installation. It is how you use in the code. You have imported `imread` and then you are trying to do `skimage.io.imread`. Python doesn't know what is `skimage` here as you haven't done `import skimage`. Changing `img = skimage.io.imread(file)` to `img = imread(file)` will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

> name 'skimage' is not defined

means that during the import

```
from skimage.io import imread `enter code here`
```

the **skimage** package can not be found

Please run a

> pip install scikit-image